# How to read a word into a string ignoring a certain character

Tags: c++, string

I am reading a text file which contains a word with a punctuation mark on it and I would like to read this word into a string without the punctuation marks.

For example, a word may be " Hello, "

I would like the string to get " Hello " (without the comma). How can I do that in C++ using ifstream libraries only.
Can I use the ignore function to ignore the last character?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to ignore `,` then you can use `getline`.

```
 const int MAX_LEN = 128;
 ifstream file("data.txt");
 char buffer[MAX_LEN];

 while(file.getline(buffer,MAX_LEN,','))
 {
  cout<<buffer;
 }
```

**EDIT:** This uses `std::string` and does away with `MAX_LEN`

```
ifstream file("data.txt");
string string_buffer;    
while(getline(file,string_buffer,','))
{
  cout<<string_buffer;
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, the only problem is that I would like to store the word into an string. How can I do that?

Comment: I think so. I just want to store it into a string type variable. Something that I would declare as: string mystring

So I could store the word "Hello," without the comma into "mystring". Thus if I decide to call "mystring" I can just say: cout << mystring

Would the EDITED part work by itself, or does it need the first part of the code? 

Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: One more question. What is the purpose of the "c_str" at the end of the string variable?

Comment: So, the word is stored in `std::string` now. `c_str()` returns a null-terminated sequence of characters (a C-style string). It's not required, you can directly display `std::string` with cout - I've updated it to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try ifstream::get(Ch* p, streamsize n, Ch term).

An example:

```
char buffer[64];
std::cin.get(buffer, 64, ',');
// will read up to 64 characters until a ',' is found
// For the string "Hello," it would stream in "Hello"
```

If you need to be more robust than simply a comma, you'll need to post-process the string.  The steps might be:

1. Read the stream into a string
2. Use string::find_first_of() to help "chunk" the words
3. Return the word as appropriate.

If I've misunderstood your question, please feel free to elaborate!

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation of how to ignore characters other than a comma. I just have a doubt. Just like my comment in the above answer. If I get the word using a char variable (buffer), how can I store the complete characters into a string (wordstring). So I could then show the word in other parts of the problem by simply calling the string (wordstring). 
Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the Boost String Algorithms library.  There are [several "replace" functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1685691) that can be used to replace (or remove) specific characters or strings in strings.

You can also use the [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) library for splitting the string into words after you have removed the punctuation marks.